# sequence contains no elements exception

Tags: asp.net-core, exception

```
             if (apply == null)
                    return StatusCode(500);

                var info = _context.TPersonalInformation.FromSql("exec dbo.SavePersonalInfoValues {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22},{23},{24},{25},{26},{27}",apply.PersonalInformationID, apply.ApplicationDate, apply.FirstName, apply.MiddleInitial, apply.LastName, apply.Email, apply.Phone, apply.EmergencyPhone, apply.IsFuturePromotion, apply.IsTextMessage, apply.Education, apply.School, apply.Age, apply.Dob, apply.SSNo, apply.ExpirationDate, apply.SSCardFront,apply.SSCardBack , apply.IsUSCitizen ,apply.IsGreenCard ,apply.GreenCardFront ,apply.GreenCardBack , apply.IsWorkPermit ,apply.WorkPermitFront ,apply.WorkPermitBack ,apply.GreenCardExpirationDate ,apply.WorkPermitExpirationDate,apply.EditMode ).ToList();

                var result = info.Single();
```

Comment: Well `info` obviously contains no elements (rows) so the `.Single()` operation will throw an exception. If you want to handle there being none then use `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.